# Is there a way to share a MS Word document while hiding comments?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a .docx file with comments. I want to share the file, but I do not want viewers to see the comments. How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Why not make a copy, delete the comments, and then distribute that? Or, use the Inspect Document tool in File to strip personal info, including comments, from the document?

Comment: @InterLinked Thanks for mentioning Inspect Document. Although the comments I have in my .docx file are sensitive in nature, and not necessarily personal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Word* menu `Review`, unselect comments to be shown. Then save the file in `.pdf` format. It won't contain the comments.

[image: Review menu in Word]

Comment: In case it helps anyone: english version of picture: https://imgur.com/U5i9NTG.png

Answer (score 1):

You can go to `Review` tab and select `Delete all comments in Document` as shown below - just remember to save it as **another copy** first!

[image]